# Rails - routing to a parent show page with a child_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to route to the parent (journal) show page after deleting the child (habit) using the child_id.

In my app, a User can create journals, which then have multiple habits. I would like to be able to delete (and edit) a habit and then return to the journal show page, which displays all of the habits.

Getting the following and similar errors:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HabitsController#destroy

**journal.rb**

```
class Journal < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :entries
    has_many :habits

    belongs_to :user
end
```

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :journal

    has_many :completed_dates
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
            <h3>Habits</h3>
            <% @journal.habits.each do |habit| %>
                <div iv class="habit-list">
                    <div class="habit-name"><%= habit.name %></div>
                    <div class="habit-status">
                        <%= simple_form_for [@journal, @habit] do |f| %>
                            <%= f.input :status, label: false, :inline_label => true %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <%= link_to habit_path(habit), method: :delete do %>
                        <i class="fas fa-trash btn-edit"></i>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

**habits_controller.rb**

```
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_journal, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
        @habits = Habit.all.sort_by &:name
    end

    def new
        @habit = Habit.new
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        @habit = @journal.habits.new(habit_params)
        if @habit.save
            redirect_to journal_path(@journal)
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @journal.habits.update(habit_params)
            redirect_to journals_path(@journal)
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @habit.destroy
        redirect_to journal_path(@habit, @journal)
    end

    private

    def habit_params
        params.require(:habit).permit(:name, :status, :user_id, :journal_id)
    end

    def set_journal
        @journal = Journal.find(params[:journal_id])
    end

    def set_habit
        @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to create URL to a deleted resource (@habit).
Change

```
def destroy
  @habit.destroy
  redirect_to journal_path(@habit, @journal)
end
```

to

```
def destroy
  @habit.destroy
  redirect_to journal_path(@journal)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! But with this I get "Couldn't find Journal without an ID" :/